# I can't figure out why my javascript isn't working... I'm dynamically passing values to a tag

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I have the below code:

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <script>
 var Orderid = 12345;
 var Quantity = 2;
 var Revenue = 10.50;
 var Red = NorthAmerica;
 var Blue = Canada;
 var Green = French;
 var Yellow = 20.00;

 document.write('<s' + 'cript language="JavaScript" src="http://jact.atdmt.com/jaction/JavaScriptTest/v3/ato.' + Orderid + '/[atm1.' + Quantity + '/atm2.' + Revenue + '/atc1.' + Red + '/atc2.' + Blue + '/atc3.' + Green + '/atc4.' + Yellow + ']"></s'+'cript>')

 document.write('<nos' + 'cript><iframe src="http://iact.atdmt.com/iaction/JavaScriptTest/v3/ato.' + Orderid + '/[atm1.' + Quantity + '/atm2.' + Revenue + '/atc1.' + Red + '/atc2.' + Blue + '/atc3.' + Green + '/atc4.' + Yellow + ']" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0"></iframe></nosc' + 'ript>')
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The purpose of this is to pass variables to a URL (action tag) for tracking on a webpage.

I've always done it like this in the past, but for some reason my action tag (jact.atdmt.com or iact.atdmt.com) is not being called this time. Am I doing something wrong that I'm not catching? Ideally I would like to keep using the same format as above... I just can't think of why it would not be working.

Thanks,

Comment: Your second `document.write` is a bit useless isn't it? Since the `noscript` tag will be used when the browser doesn't have JS enabled. And where are `NorthAmerica` and the two other variables below that one defined?

Comment: document.write('<nos' + 'cript>....
not tied to your issue, but how this code must executed?  if user disable javascript - document.write will not working neither lol

Comment: `'<s' + 'cript` & `'<nos' + 'cript>` are rather confusing.  It doesn't matter but why are you separating the strings there?

Comment: That's true. I can fix that. Even if I just include the first tag however, it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: I break the script and noscript tags up because I thought we werent allowed to embed a script tag in another script tag without doing this. So I think I'm essentially making it a string in this case.

Comment: Everything inside the quotes in document.write is a string.  Try adding `type="text/javascript"`.  Also make your variable strings strings like @MattK explained below

Comment: Yup, making my variables strings did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around those strings or else they will be treated as undefined variables...

```
var Red = 'NorthAmerica';
var Blue = 'Canada';
var Green = 'French';
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed this! It's working now :). I will accept your answer in 5 minutes when I am able to!

Comment: @user2946613 no worries, next time open up the developer console and you can view that kind of error there.